# how to integrate a software to run from another?

Tags: windows, matlab, dll, exe

I am working on a project and I am using a closed software package. In this software I browse for images on my computer and run the program and it executes. What I want to do is create a matlab gui where I browse the images from matlab itself and make a push button that executes the software. 
what kind of files do I need to work on in order to be able to integrate the function of a certain feature in a program to run from another one?

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be divided into 2 parts.

```
1. How to run external program from Matlab?
```

To do that, you need first find out how to run your program using `cmd`. Once you know that, you can create a string with system commands in Matlab, that you can pass to `cmd` using [`system`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html). Learn the arguments and syntax that you need to following during the `system` call. Wrap the whole routine into a function to be further used in GUI.

```
2. How to embed my program into GUI?
```

Consult the [guide](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/about-the-simple-guide-gui-example.html) on Mathworks website. All you need to do is to instruct Matlab to run your function from previous part using the user-set arguments.

The rest is technicalities and you might need to ask more specific questions in future.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will be searching more into that.